# Why is my radix sorting algorithm returning a partially sorted list?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

First off I want to point out that **this assignment is homework** /but/ I am not looking for a direct answer, but rather at **a hint** or **some insight** as to why my implementation is not working.

Here is the given: *We are provided with a list of words of 7 characters long each and are asked to sort them using the Radix Sorting Algorithm while using queues.*

**EDIT 1: Updated Code**

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

    public class RadixSort {

  public void radixSort() {
    ArrayList<LinkedQueue> arrayOfBins = new ArrayList<LinkedQueue>();
    LinkedQueue<String> masterQueue = new LinkedQueue<String>();
    LinkedQueue<String> studentQueue = new LinkedQueue<String>();

//Creating the bins
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  arrayOfBins.add(new LinkedQueue<String>());
}
// Getting the file name and reading the lines from it
try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the file name with its extension: ");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine());
        input = new Scanner(file);

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            masterQueue.enqueue(line);
        }
        input.close();

 } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
 }


 for (int p = 6; p >= 0; p--) { 
    for (LinkedQueue queue : arrayOfBins) {
      queue.clear();
    }
    while (masterQueue.isEmpty() == false) {
        String s = (String) masterQueue.dequeue();
        char c = s.charAt(p);
        arrayOfBins.get(c-'a').enqueue(s);      
     }

      for (LinkedQueue queue : arrayOfBins) {
         studentQueue.append(queue);
      } 
 }

 masterQueue = studentQueue;

 System.out.println(masterQueue.size());
 System.out.println(masterQueue.dequeue());


}

public static void main(String [] args) {
  RadixSort sort = new RadixSort();
  sort.radixSort();
 }
}
```

Comment: Normally a radix sort is done from least significant character to most significant character. This allows the bins from one radix sort pass to be concatenated into a single bin for the next pass.

Comment: I can see so many problems, I'm not sure how you get an answer at all.  Why do you have *two* nested outermost loops from 0 to 6?  Why don't you ever clear `studentQueue`?  The `j` loop doesn't execute as many times as you think it does.  Aside from definite bugs, the program doesn't output anything -- are you just looking at the result in the debugger?  Also are you actually allowed to assume that the words will contain no characters besides lowercase letters?

Comment: And if the algorithm you're trying to implement is to start at the most significant character, partition by character, then concatenate and then repeat, this *algorithm* is wrong (as pointed out by @rcgldr) -- although there exists a different most-significant-character-first algorithm that needs recursion, and which is correct.

Comment: @rcgldr thank you, so in the for loop, I should start with 6, all the way down to 0, correct?

Comment: @j_random_hacker thanks for the criticism! I realize my mistake with the the outer loop and will be fixing it now. I only had one for loop originally but I saw people's code online and thought I was mistaken. I will be updating my code in a few :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Okay I've updated my code! (still the wrong output though). Anyway, would you mind explaining why I have to clear studentQueue?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I solved it! Would you mind adding your suggestions as an answer so I can accept them? They helped a lot!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get things working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see so many problems, I'm not sure how you get an answer at all.

- Why do you have two nested outermost loops from 0 to 6?
- Why don't you ever clear `studentQueue`?
- The j loop doesn't execute as many times as you think it does.

Aside from definite bugs, the program doesn't output anything -- are you just looking at the result in the debugger? Also are you actually allowed to assume that the words will contain no characters besides lowercase letters?